# Get the values of the form and replace variables in textarea

Tags: javascript, php, forms

Hi i'm currently stuck with a task: I've to create a form on a page with fields and texarea.

i have to put info in fields and a text in textarea with variables : "hi my name is $name and i live at @adress...."

The values of these variables comes from fields of the form.

when i press on button it should change the $name by the value. So i'll get "hi my name is john".

And the idea would be to stay on same page.

This an example :

```
  <html>
  <form action="values.php" method="get">
   Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name"><br>
   Adress<input id="name" type="text" name="adress"><br>
   Phone<input id="name" type="text" name="phone" ><br>
   Textarea<input id="textarea" type="text" name="textarea"> Hi my name is $name and    you can call me on this number : $phone<br>
   <input type="submit">
   </form>
```

/*Result after clicking a button*/
        Hi my name is John and you can call me on this number : 77665555544 // Result i want to obtain whithout leaving the page

My code in values.php is :

```
<?php
$description= $_GET["textarea"];
$description = str_replace( '$name',$_GET["name"],$description); 
$description = str_replace( '$adress',$_GET["adress"],$description);
$description = str_replace( '$phone',$_GET["phone"],$description);
echo "<textarea>$description</textarea>";
?>
```

Comment: Could you, clearly, explain what do you want?

Comment: ok i added some explanation, is it a bit more clear like this? Thks!

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple to be done, if I understood correctly. You can see a working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/ah9qp/

After the user has clicked on submit, you need to stop the form from actually submitting. This can be done by using the following: e.preventDefault();

After this, you need to grab all the values you want to output from the input boxes. You can do that by using the jquery .val(); This will get the value of the input. In order to get this though you have to have a specific ID associated with each input element. Below is your form modified to hear and interact with Jquery:

```
<form action="" method="get" id="formit">
   Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="John"><br>
   Adress<input id="address" type="text" name="adress"><br>
   Phone<input id="phone" type="text" name="phone" value="77665555544"><br>
   Textarea<textarea id="textarea" rows="5">Hello my name is $name and you can call me at this: $phone</textarea><br>
   <input type="submit" id="textit">
   </form>
```

Once you form is set up correctly, all you need to do is add in the jquery file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

and last you need to create the code using jquery that will achieve what you need:

```
$("#textit").click(function(e){
   //prevents the form from submitting
    e.preventDefault();
    //get variables from input
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    //set var to textarea for output
    var textarea = $("#textarea");

    textarea.val("Hi my name is "+name+" and you can call me on this number: "+phone);
});
```

You will see the id's in the form are being called by jquery and outputted. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes it's working fine but just one remark : we have texarea filled too in the form with text like : Hi my name is $name and    you can call me on this number : $phone   and when you click on submit it replaces the $name and $phone in this textarea

Comment: It does the same thing, by using the val(); you are replacing the entire code. It is the same as str_replace. If you want to achieve str_replace in jquery you would do this:
textarea.replace('$name',name);
textarea.replace('$phone',phone);

These are really your only two options if you want to place text in textareas. If the answer worked for you please checkmark! Thanks!

Comment: i followed youre recommandation on http://jsfiddle.net/sebflorent/Tjf99/ but i'm still doing something wrong, it's not working :(

Comment: Do you have a link I could see??

Comment: Ok first of all you can not replace something that is not physically there. Are you using php to output the $name and $phone element? This code:
    textarea.change('$name',name);
    textarea.replace('$adresse',adress);
    textarea.replace('$phone',phone);
Can not find anything... becuase it is no where in the html.

Comment: ok i want to fill the form as you know and thought by clicking submit it would use the fields to replace $values in textarea. And in same way i thought i could avoid the use of  this php file.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand... this does exactly what the php files does...
Please see this again... If this is not what you are asking for you need to make your self clearer. Thanks
SEE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/ah9qp/1/

Comment: your example sounds good but you place the value of texarea in javascript. I want the user to put himself the text in html side, and then, on clicking button, it replaces automatically. Here is some illsutration : http://awesomescreenshot.com/0512gp1rb2

Comment: I am sorry, that is about as much as I can do for you, I do not understand when or why anyone would do this. You would have to convert the textarea to a div instead. Within a text area it is much more difficult to do, you are quite limited. You could do a search and replace, but how do you know the user will always use this: $name variable??

Comment: in fact i am the user. The text in textarea is some kind of template to do description and personnalise it with infos like adress, name, etc... But yes generate an other div could be good idea in order to replace the variables $name $phone...

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent submiting the form (refreshing the page), and fill the textarea with the values.
Example:

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
    /* rest of the script */
    event.preventDefault();
});
```